# Cumulative Flow Diagram in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is there a way I can create a CFD - Cumulative Flow Diagram in Azure DevOps that gives the diagram across all teams?

The existing CFD looks like Team specific but what if I have 10 teams and i need one consolidated report?

Answer (score 0):

> The existing CFD looks like Team specific but what if I have 10 teams and i need one consolidated report?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed** and CFDs help **teams** monitor the count of work items as they progressively move through various workflow states. There is no way to create consolidated report for across all teams.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At the Portfolio level it's very useful to have such feature when I want to see how all the teams together progressively moving through various workflow stages to deliver the end product/solution/system together. I will add a request for this feature.

Comment: @Asif one option to consider is using [PowerBI to get a cross team CFD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-cfd?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi#pull-in-data-from-multiple-teams)

Comment: @Eric Smith - Thanks a lot! This is something hopefully I can work with as an alternative solution. The CFD that is available in ADO as widget is very quick & easy but I wish I could extend it for multiple teams which is not possible as I come to know from this thread.

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT, Thanks. I accept Eric Smith's answer as a good solution. If you want, you can archive the thread.